# Spark - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in a scala jar built with Maven

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I am trying to generate in Eclipse (exactly with sts-3.8.2.RELEASE) a jar from a scala project. I am going to reproduce the whole process:

Firstly I created a Maven project using maven-archetype-quickstart 1.1, and in configured I added the Scala Nature.

Then I went to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder and under src I added `/main/scala` and also `/test/scala`

I removed the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` since I am not going to use them.

Finally in Properties -> Scala Compiler -> Use Project Settings I selected: `Fixed Scala Installation: 2.10.6(built-in)`

So the structure of my project is like follows:

[image]

Then I created two simple objects scripts:

**App.scala**

```
package com.examples

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val mParam1 = args(0).trim()
    val mParam2 = args(1).trim()
    DataProcessing.Processing(mParam1, mParam2)
  }
}
```

**DataProcesing.sala**

```
package com.examples

object DataProcessing {
  def Processing(param1 : String, param2 : String){
    println("The Param1 is: "+param1)
    println("The Param2 is: "+param2)
  }
}
```

Now to generate a Jar I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html)

So my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestScala</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestScala</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.examples.TestScala.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I Run As -> Maven build -> I introduced the following goals:

```
clean package
```

I got:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.076 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-11T12:50:08+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/145M
```

Then  Maven -> Update Project -> checked Force Update of Snapshot/Releases

So the jar was generated. Now the project looks like:

[image]

Finally I commit to a cluster the jar and I run it using spark-submit (This is because in the future I want to create a Spark project based on this)

```
spark-submit --class com.examples.TestScala.App --master yarn://12.234.67.89:7077 --deploy-mode cluster /home/user/TestScala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "path" "date"
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
reason: Uncaught exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.examples.TestScala.App
```

I also want to mention after reading this [post](http://2mohitarora.blogspot.ae/2011/12/maven-shade-plugin-better-than-maven.html) I tried to change the plugin to build the application (since I have no dependencies so far not sure if it will make any effect). So with this new pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestScala</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestScala</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>TestScala.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the I chosed the highlighted jar (the shaded) to run in the cluster.

[image]

But I have the same error.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time and help